# How do you insert a input name="title0" in the title column in the rails column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you insert a input name="title0" in the title column in the rails column?
plz using params.require().permit()

```
@bank = Bank.new(params.require(:bank).permit(:title))
```

this is POST title => DB column title

but I want is POST title0 => DB column title

Sorry, i am bad at english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, refactor your code as described [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). So, your code will become

```
def probably_create_action
  @bank = Bank.new(bank_params)
end
...
private

def bank_params
  params.require(:bank).permit(:param1, :param2, :param3, :title0)
end
```

Attributes not listed inside `bank_params` method will not be passed.

**UPDATE**

Fighting with conventions is not a good practice. But below snippet might save your day.

```
#app/models/bank.rb
def title0=(inp) 
  self.title = inp
end
```

Comment: I want to submit the 'title' column to the 'title0' by post